# extract ip address from sh ip int brief using interface name in tcl

Tags: networking, tcl, expect

I am new to TCL and Expect.I tried to extract ip address of a particular interface using the interface name.

sample input:

```
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Embedded-Service-Engine0/0 unassigned      YES NVRAM  administratively down down    
GigabitEthernet0/0         unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.10      10.1.1.1        YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/0.20      20.1.1.2        YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/1         192.168.2.1   YES NVRAM  up                    up      
GigabitEthernet0/2         192.168.1.1   YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

I tried this,

```
regexp -line ^ $interfacename.*?(?=(?:\\..*?)?\\d{1,}) $temp
```

but its not giving me any answers.... Can somebody help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to extract the IP address? Example, for "GigabitEthernet/1" you want 192.168.2.1, correct?

If yes:

```
% set interfacename GigabitEthernet0/1
GigabitEthernet0/1
% set re "^$interfacename\\s+(\[\\d.]+)"
^GigabitEthernet0/1\s+([\d.]+)
% regexp -inline -line $re $input
{GigabitEthernet0/1         192.168.2.1} 192.168.2.1
% regexp -line $re $input -> ip
1
% set ip
192.168.2.1
```

You don't need a lookahead here. Also, you don't want a space after the `^` character.